# How to add soft attributes(by loading) to WTPart?

Tags: ptc-windchill

In Windchill 10.2,how to add global soft attributes to WTPart? I mean by load file.
windchill wt.load.LoadFromFile -d update-wtpart.xml

I want to know how to write that update-wtpart.xml file.

Comment: You have to refer `WC Data Loading and Best practices` guide to know more about data loading.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you must have got a solution to your problem, but incase not then i am assuming you have a WTPart in Windchill and IBA as well you just need to add that IBA to WTPart.
You must use

- wt.part.LoadPart.cachePart loadfile

You will find one example provided by PTC in loadFiles folder.

Comment: Yeah,I got the solution, by the way what's wt.part.LoadPart.cachePart? Sounds not a java class.